# How to reduce image data size without changing its resolution?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

I have tried couple of ways to reduce image size, but all failed. All similar to this:

```
    //Mat frame...
    vector<uchar> buff;
    vector<int> params;
    params.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    params.push_back(50); //Tried any value here, didn't change much

    cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff, params);
    Mat a = cv::imdecode(buff,1);
    // a size is bigger than frame's
```

How can one reduce an image (Mat object) size without changing its resolution?

**Edit:**

I'm taking frames from camera and making video of them. Saving the frames as is makes a 1 minute video to weight about 100mb, which is totally unacceptable. How can I reduce the size (number of bytes) of each frame?

Comment: Size of what? The compressed size?

Comment: look at the edit. I thought compressing and decompressing will reduce the image size, which it doesn't.

Comment: This will degrade quality. When you decompress with different quantization tables, JPEG images degrade.

Comment: The Question is, what quality do you need? You cant have full HD and 7KB per image at the same time.

Comment: I need to reduce each frame size even if it means reducing quality.

Answer (score 0):

You need [video compression like mpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) instead of image compression.

Another way might be to first blur the image and them encode to jpeg. Blurring will reduce entropy and so the image might compress better. Considering that you are not satisfied with the JPEG compression, to reduce image size I guess you can't escape reducing quality, blurring might not be the worst solution, it depends on your problem.

Comment: agree. and maybe use VideoWriter class (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) with some lossless compression option (http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)?